# Distinguish zero and negative zero with java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java

Is it possible to distinguish `new BigDecimal(-0D)` from `new BigDecimal(0D)`?

Comment: Where is the difference between both zeros?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer They are different. `Double.doubleToLongBits(0D)` gives `0`, `Double.doubleToLongBits(-0D)` gives `-9223372036854775808`.

Comment: "Negative" zero is a side effect of number storage format. `BigDecimal` doesn't use formats like this. While `BigDecimal.ZERO.negate()` does produce a distinct object, that still won't let you do anything with it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Positive and negative zero do have a mathematical value when considering limits, etc; they are not only a side-effect of storage. The fact IEEE-754 floating points support them is because of that mathematical value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, IEEE-754 has that because they store sign in a first bit, just as I said - a side effect of chosen storage format. I would never look at a zero like this. It's not a "property" of a number to "know" that it is being approached to, as then it is not a number (i.e. not a point of numeric field). It is a property of limit specifically.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov As far as I know in IEEE-754 it is not a side-effect, it is an intentional design decision by William Kahan, because of its useful applications. They could just as well have specified that the sign bit must not be set for zero.

Comment: @MArkRotteveel, I doubt this is a decision made because they actually wanted specifically the zero to be able to signify being approached to, as nowhere in there it states the reason. I'd rather say it was done because of existence of a legacy system so major that it's easier to include a weird exception in the standard (as many do, when they are trying to unify competing implementations) than to fix that system and all the ripple that comes from that fix.

Comment: Correction: I've dug into this, and it's not because of a legacy systems, but instead it's because not every computation result is representable in floating-point arythmetics considering the precision of that number, so certain computations that produce a number very small (so it can't be represented by anything other than a zeron with given precision) should still keep their signum at the very least. That still falls under "shortcomings of a number representation" though, so my major point still stands, I think.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov But it was a a deliberate design decision by William Kahan (main architect of IEEE-754) for exactly that reason, see for example https://hackernoon.com/negative-zero-bbd5fd790af3 and https://people.freebsd.org/~das/kahan86branch.pdf That first link also includes a quote were he admits he doesn't like it, but it was a choice for the lesser evil.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yes, it is a deliberate decision to work around memory limitation and limitations imposed by selected storage format for numbers. Main point is: it exists because IEEE-754 format has problems. `BigDecimal`'s number format doesn't have the same problems so it doesn't need a signed zero. Hense it's not there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to distinguish this, because `java.math.BigDecimal` only knows a single zero(*). It doesn't have the concept of positive or negative zero.

This is because internally, `BigDecimal` uses `BigInteger`, and `BigInteger` also only has a single concept of zero. A `BigInteger` behaves as a two's-complement integer, and two's-complement only has a single zero.

See also this comment in the `BigInteger` sources:

> ```
> public class BigInteger extends Number implements Comparable<BigInteger> {
>     /**
>      * The signum of this BigInteger: -1 for negative, 0 for zero, or
>      * 1 for positive.  Note that the BigInteger zero <em>must</em> have
>      * a signum of 0.  This is necessary to ensures that there is exactly one
>      * representation for each BigInteger value.
>      */
>     final int signum
> ```

---

<sup>*: Not entirely accurate, you can have multiple zeroes with differing scale, just not with differing sign</sup>

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé Looking at the source code of `BigDecimal`, and having implemented a library that provides conversion between a IEEE-754 Decimal128 (which does have positive and negative zero) to `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé See the implementation of `BigDecimal`. In both cases `significand` is `0` so `BigDecimal` is initialized with `intVal=BigInteger.ZERO`, `scale=0`, `intCompact=0`, `precision=1`. If `significand` is `0`, sign is not taken in account.

Comment: "the BigInteger zero _must_ have a signum of 0.  This is necessary to ensures that there is exactly one representation for each BigInteger value."

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) states:

> A `BigDecimal` consists of an arbitrary precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer scale.
>
> The value of the number represented by the `BigDecimal` is therefore (unscaledValue × 10<sup>scale</sup>).

Since there is only one integer value for zero, it is impossible to represent "minus zero" as a `BigDecimal`.

---

Internally, the standard implementation of `BigDecimal` uses a `BigInteger` to represent the "unscaled value".  While the javadocs don't include this implementation detail as part the specification, the definition quoted above is sufficient to preclude any implementation where there were two distinct values for positive and negative zero.

There can of course be multiple values for zero; e.g. `0` and `0.00` are not equal.  This follows from the definition of `BigDecimal::equals(Object)`.

Comment: If a different integer representation had been chosen, it would have been entirely possible to have two (or more) zeroes, so you could argue that only the fact it uses an arbitrary precision integer is not a sufficient reason for having a single zero. It is the implementation choice for using `BigInteger`, and the fact `BigInteger` is implemented to behave as if it is two's-complement that leads two `BigDecimal` only having a single zero (`BigInteger` itself could have been implemented to distinguish between positive and negative zero, but they didn't so it would behave as two's-complement)

Comment: Hmmm ... debatable.  Certainly from a mathematical perspective, having two or more distinct values for zero is broken.   Note that the javadoc doesn't talk about a "representation" of the "unscaled value".  It calls it an integer, plain and simple.

Comment: When doing analysis involving limits having positive and negative zero can have their value, mathematically.

Comment: Re _"It calls it an integer, plain and simple."_, if Java had used one's-complement for its integer representation (or if `BigInteger` had been implemented to behave as one's complement), then `BigDecimal` would very likely have had two zeroes, as integer in one's-complement does know two zeroes. So just the fact it uses an integer is not a sufficient reason. (I know, this is a bit far-fetched argument ;)

Comment: Yes.  But I return to the argument that the wording of the javadocs don't talk about the representation of the "unscaled value".  An integer is a purely mathematical concept ... independent of representation.  One's complement is a (flawed) representation of integers.  They are not integers *per se*.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, when working with limits, you aren't really working with numbers - you are working with numeric fields, and limit is the function of the field you've defined, not the number itself. Mathematically, the case where signed zero may come up (division by zero) makes _zero_ (hah) sense, it's result is not defined for real numbers.