# Why BigDecimal.Zero exist in Java where as Double.zero doesn't

Tags: java, spring-boot, double, bigdecimal, autoboxing

I am curious to understand why do we see BigDecimal.Zero but not Double.Zero, so if we need to assign a double variable as Zero then we need to cast it to (double) 0.

Any specific reasons creators added a special zero variable for bigdecimal.

Comment: *so if we need to assign a double variable as Zero then we need to cast it to (double) 0.* We don't. As @user16320675 has just said, we assign `0.0`

Comment: You can also use `0D` or `0d` instead of `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

> so if we need to assign a `double` variable as Zero then we need to cast it to `(double) 0`.

No. This compiles:

```
double d = 0;
```

so does this:

```
double d = 0.0;
```

The first one works because assignment contexts allow a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) (from `int` to `double`).

If you're talking about the `Double` wrapper, this also compiles:

```
Double d = 0.0;
```

There *is* a zero value for `double` that you can easily write - in fact, more easily than `BigDecimal.ZERO` - it's just written `0.0`. And because assignment contexts allow a [boxing conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7), you can assign `0.0` to the wrapper `Double` too.

`BigDecimal.ZERO` is not the rule - it's the exception. The compiler knows about all the primitive numeric types, and their "zeroes" are baked into the language - `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0.0f` etc.

The compiler doesn't know about `BigDecimal`. `BigDecimal` is just a part of the JDK, the standard library, not a part of the Java *language*.

The language specifications does not say that there is a conversion from `double` to `BigDecimal` in an assignment context, so you can't do

```
BigDecimal d = 0.0;
```

And that's why there is `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

Comment: `double d = 0;` *compiles* as it undergoes a [widening conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25214)

Comment: @g00se I didn't think that was relevant to the question at first. But upon rereading it, I guess you're right - I should include that.

Comment: You can also have negative signed zero `double d = -0.0; System.out.println(d);`
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: BigDecimal doesn't distinguish signed zeros:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774540/distinguish-zero-and-negative-zero-with-java-math-bigdecimal